# Как создать еще несколько дополнительных полей во вкладке tv прямо в ресурсе MODX Revo?

Tags: modx, revo

Я создал обычное **tv поле (файл)** и сделал доступным его для определенного шаблона. В соответствующем ресурсе во вкладке **доп поле tv** нашел это поле,; но если нужно выводить не один файл, а 3 или 10? Как можно организовать добавление таких же полей прямо из редактируемого ресурса?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам поможет пакет `MIGx` (https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/migx)

Документация на русском: https://webstool.ru/documentation-migx-russian.html

Примерно для Вашего случая (список файлов, только плюс еще описание файла):

```
Тип ввода
migx

Вкладки формы:
[{
"caption" : "Публикации работника",
"fields" : [
{
    "field" : "naimenovanie",
    "caption" : "Наименование работы",
    "inputTVtype" : "text"
},
{
    "field" : "pdf",
    "caption" : "Ссылка на pdf файл",
    "inputTVtype" : "file"
}
]
}]

Разметка колонок:
[{
"header": "Наименование публикации", "sortable": "true", "dataIndex": "naimenovanie"
},{
"header": "Ссылка на pdf файл", "sortable": "true", "dataIndex": "pdf"
}]
```

Как это выглядит в редакторе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете добавлять сколько угодно файлов

Comment: Спасибо за полный ответ, очень помогли! Продолжаю узнавать modx лучше. Оказывается полезная хрень)

Comment: Не подскажите почему выводится такая строка вместо наименования поля? [{"MIGX_id":"1","title":"Материал 1","pdf":"materiali-dlya-urokov/test.docx"}] (Наименование поля - материал 1, он выводится в середине этой строки). Через getImageList вообще ничего не выводится. Выводится только так ***[[*названиеПоля]]***

Comment: Пытаюсь так ***[[getImageList? &tvname=`stuff` &tpl=`enterStuff`]]***. В чанке ***<li>[[+stuff]]</li>*** Но нифига не выводится

Comment: Выводится нормально, это json строка - массив значений tv поля. Используется либо в снипетах которые пишете сами на php либо через getImageList. По выводу через  getImageList скорее всего неправильно указано tvname или вызов в чанке - это разные плейсхоллдеры а у вас одно и тоже. Но лучше это отдельным вопросом, с указанием шаблонов migx и как вызываете getImageList